# Architecture guidance for waiting for an event

Tags: c#, web-services, design-patterns, event-handling

I'm working on a web service call that is itself, going to be making a further web service call.  This is fire and forget and the result is returned via a webhook a short while later.  I have no control over this as it's an external system and it's just how that works.

I need the originating web service call to wait for the response from the webhook, before processing that and returning it's own result.  The other complicating factor is that the webhook retrieves multiples items and I only want the appropriate one returned to the original web service call.

I'm honestly not sure how to architect this.  Initially I was thinking on the observer pattern, and having the original service call subscribing to the webhook and getting results as they come in.  The problem with this is it's all happening within the original web service call.  I need it to wait for a result from the webhook, and it seems it won't do this if delegate a method as the event handler.  Basically how do I get that information back to the originating call.

Thanks for any guidance!

Comment: Usually for callback things I just add a Task that will be resolved when things come back. So this call adds information for the webhook to handle (request ID or something that is known in the hook) and then waits for the task to be completed by the webhook handler (probably with a timeout)

Comment: Thanks Sami, so just thinking through this.  Original web service call is made and that creates a private accessible Task, then subscribes to the webhook, sets a delegate and awaits for the Task to complete.  Then within the delete method, once the webhook has responded set the Task to complete?  Have I got that right?

Comment: I would make the webhook handle the task. The original place just makes an async call and awaits it. The webhook has a list of tasks it needs to complete when response comes and handles it. This way the caller doesn’t need to know what happens on the other side, it just makes a call and gets a result at some point.

Comment: ah I think I get you.  So the webhook will basically have an enumeration of Tasks.  Each time it does get a response come in it checks the outstanding tasks to find the one the resposne if for and completes that?

Comment: Yep. This way there’s no delegates and no connections between things, just a task. There has to be some identifier how to know what response links to what request so it can find the suitable one to complete. I use this way in several places where response comes later on.